# How to show date column in horizontal format in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns in my Product table :-

```
  Product          |       Date
--------------------------------------
     Prod1       |     06/01/2018
     Prod2       |     06/03/2018
     Prod3       |     06/05/2018
```

I want the output the as :-

```
 Product | 06/01/2018 | 06/02/2018 | 06/03/2018| 06/04/2018 | 06/05/2018
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Prod1 |     X           -            -           -            -
     Prod2 |     -           -            X           -            -
     Prod3 |     -           -            -           -            X
```

I want to display this table in a grid. Is this possible by writing a query in sql ?

Comment: `is this possible by writing a query in sql ??` SQL is Turing complete language. Anyway please search for PIVOT/conditional aggregation

Comment: Personally, I would suggest doing so in your presentation layer.

Comment: you can use a `pivot`, but you will either end up hard-coding the date values into the `pivot` or writing some fairly long winded dynamic sql. What is the presentation layer for this (SSRS)?

Comment: output to be displayed in html grid

Answer (score 1):

Using Dynamic Sql

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp')IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Temp
DECLARE @temp AS TABLE (Product varchar(10), [Date] DATE)

INSERT INTO @temp
 SELECT 'Product1',    '06/01/2018' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Product2',    '06/03/2018' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Product3',    '06/05/2018' 

DECLARE @StartDate DATE,
        @EndDate DATE      

SELECT @StartDate=MIN([Date])
        ,@EndDate=MAX([Date]) 
FROM @temp

;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT Number,
        DATEADD(DAY,Number,@StartDate) AS ReqDays
FROM master.dbo.spt_values WHERE Number BETWEEN 0 AND 100
    AND DATEADD(DAY,Number,@StartDate) BETWEEN @StartDate  AND @EndDate
)
SELECT  Product,
        ReqDays  AS [Date] INTO #Temp 
FROM CTE c
LEFT JOIN @temp t
On c.ReqDays=t.[Date]

DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max),
        @Col  nvarchar(max),
        @Col2  nvarchar(max)

SELECT @Col=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+QUOTENAME([Date]) FROM #Temp FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
SELECT @Col2=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+'ISNULL('+QUOTENAME([Date])+','' '') AS '+QUOTENAME([Date]) FROM #Temp FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

SET @Sql='
SELECT Product,'+@Col2+'
FROM
(
SELECT *,IIF(DATALENGTH(Product)>0,''X'','''') AS Producttemp FROM #Temp
)AS Src
PIVOT 
(MAX([Producttemp]) FOR [Date] IN ('+@Col+')
)AS PVT WHERE Product IS NOT NULL'
PRINT @Sql
EXEC (@Sql)
```

Result

```
Product     2018-06-01  2018-06-02  2018-06-03  2018-06-04  2018-06-05
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Product1        X                
Product2                                X        
Product3                                                        X
```

Comment: thanks , can we get all the days horizontally in the row from 1july to 30 july , so that it looks like a calender format

Comment: @KazaAvinash i written code as your expected output

Comment: Add new expected output so that i can modify the code

Comment: insted of product name under the date column , can we display 'X' character  ?

Comment: @KazaAvinash You should not change your requirements so often. It is considered a better practice to upvote a useful answer and then if you have follow up questions, post a new question on SO.

Comment: @KazaAvinash ,just modified code ,check it you will get result as you expected

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that also uses Dynamic SQL with a PIVOT.

Except that how the column names are generates is done slightly different.

And [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) is used instead of just EXEC.

```
--
-- Using a temporary table for testing reasons
--
if object_id('tempdb..#Test_Products')IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Test_Products;
create table #Test_Products (Product varchar(30), [Date] date);

--
-- Sample data
--
insert into #Test_Products (Product, [Date]) values
('Prod1', '2018-06-01'),
('Prod2', '2018-06-03'),
('Prod3', '2018-06-05');

--
-- Getting the begindate and enddate. This can also be set to hardcoded values.
--
declare @BeginDate date = (select min([Date]) from #Test_Products);
declare @EndDate date = (select max([Date]) from #Test_Products);

declare @SQL nvarchar(800);
declare @ColNames varchar(500);

--
-- Using a Recursive SQL to get all dates, then use those to get the column names
--
with RCTE as 
(
  select @BeginDate as startdate
  union all
  select dateadd(day,1,startdate)
  from RCTE where startdate < @EndDate
)
select @ColNames = concat(@ColNames+', ', quotename(convert(varchar,startdate,101))) 
from RCTE;

--
-- Generating the Dynamic SQL statement
--
set @SQL = 'select *
from 
(
  select Product, convert(varchar(10),[Date],101) as DateStamp, ''X'' as X
  from #Test_Products
  where [Date] between @BeginDate and @EndDate
  group by Product, [Date]
) src
pivot (
  max(X)
  for DateStamp 
  in ('+ @ColNames +')
) as pvt';

-- select @SQL as SQL;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
        N'@BeginDate date, @EndDate date', 
        @BeginDate = @BeginDate, 
        @EndDate = @EndDate;
```

**Result:**

```
Product 06/01/2018 06/02/2018 06/03/2018 06/04/2018 06/05/2018
------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Prod1   X          NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL
Prod2   NULL       NULL       X          NULL       NULL
Prod3   NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       X
```